# Python virtualenv issue on virtualbox

Tags: python, virtualbox, virtualenv, symlink

Hello all I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 11, in <module>
sys.exit(main())
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 708, in main
symlink=options.symlink)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 921, in create_environment
     site_packages=site_packages, clear=clear, symlink=symlink))
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1353, in    install_python
     os.symlink(py_executable_base, full_pth)
 OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system
```

I am trying to install my test environment in a shared file between my windows host 7 and Ubuntu guest.

I googled around and found this [tutorial](http://www.ahtik.com/blog/fixing-your-virtualbox-shared-folder-symlink-error/)

I got it to work and running

```
 VBoxManage getextradata 5bc6053b-bc8b-42c7-9c58-24935d281a82 enumerate
```

yielded:

```
 Key: GUI/LastCloseAction, Value: PowerOff
 Key: GUI/LastGuestSizeHint, Value: 1218,736
 Key: GUI/LastNormalWindowPosition, Value: 70,30,624,282,max
 Key: GUI/RestrictedRuntimeDevicesMenuActions, Value: HardDrives
 Key: GUI/RestrictedRuntimeMachineMenuActions, Value: SaveState,PowerOff
 Key: GUI/StatusBar/IndicatorOrder, Value: HardDisks,OpticalDisks,FloppyDisks,Network,USB,SharedFolders,Display,VideoCapture,Features,Mouse,Keyboard
 Key: VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/sv_vmShare, Value: 1

 C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox>
```

Of note:

```
  Key: VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/sv_vmShare, Value: 1
```

Would seem to indicate sym-links are on and functional, however even after a reboot of both the guest and the host still yield the protocol error. 
e

EDIT:

Can run virtualenv inside the /home/ file of the guest vm its only the shared folder that is giving me the problem. I really want to do my work out of the shared folder to make it simpler to develop